# IIS - is garbage collection shared between app pools?

Tags: iis, garbage-collection, application-pool, garbage

So we have multiple application pools in iis for multiple web applications, is garbage collection shared between all of these app pools or does each app pool have its own garbage collection ?

Comment: Short answer: No. Each app pool is hosted by its own process with .NET runtime inside that has its own GC. The only shared resources are on the OS/hardware level - CPU, memory etc.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would be the case but with the behaviour i was experiencing i just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage Collection is Process specific (w3wp.exe) and each application pool is associated with a w3wp process irrespective of number of applications running within it.

So if you have multiple applications within a single application pool and if one of the application triggers a GC, all threads within the process will be stalled until GC completes and hence impacting other applications as well .

On the other hand, if each application has its own respective application pool, GC triggered in one application will not impact the other applications.

Hope this answers ! Please feel free to ask any follow up questions.